# Show that $N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(O_L^*)=\{1\}$ and deduce that $[O_L^*:O_K^*]=3$ if $p=3$ and $[O_L^*:O_K^*]=1$ if $p\ne3$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm studying for the Algebraic Number Theory exam and I can't solve the problem from last year's exam. Here is the question:

Consider the real quadratic field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})\subset\mathbb{R}$, and the quadratic field $L=K(\sqrt{-p})\subset\mathbb{C}$ where $p$ is a prime number.

(a) Prove that $\eta=3+\sqrt{10}$ is a fundumental unit of $K$, i.e. $O_K^*=<-1,\eta>$.

(b) Show that $O_K^*$ has a finite index in $O_L^*$.

(c) Show that $[O_L^*:O_K^*]$ divides 6.

(d) Show that $N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(O_L^*)=\{1\}$ and deduce that $[O_L^*:O_K^*]=3$ if $p=3$ and $[O_L^*:O_K^*]=1$ if $p\ne3$

So far I was able only to prove that $\eta$ is a fundamental unit (by looking at the norm and solving the Pell equation). I also think that the rank of the unit group $O_L^*$ is $2+1-1=2$, but I can't move any further.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Hint for part (b): the question says that $\mathcal O_K^* \subseteq \mathcal O_L^*$ is finite index, which implies $ \mathcal O_L^*$ should be rank 1. I guess you are calculating it using Dedekind's unit theorem, so it looks like you have counted the number of real and complex embeddings of $L$ incorrectly. Note that $\sqrt{-p}$ can never be embedded into $\mathbf R$.

Comment: Thank you! I see, so there should be 4 complex embeddings and 0 real ones, so the rank is $0 +4/2 -1=1$... But how to compute the index? Should I look for a fundamental unit in $O_L^*$ ?