# Computing index of unit groups of rings of integers without explicitely computing them

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

The number fields are $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})$ and $L=K(\sqrt{-p})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10},\sqrt{-p})=\mathbb{Q}[x]/\left(x^4-(20-2p)x^2+(p+10)^2\right)$ where I already proved the last equality where the polynomial has the root $\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{-p}$.

> The problem is to show that $[\mathscr{O}_L^*:\mathscr{O}_K^*]=3,1$
>   for $p=3$ or $p\neq3$ respectively.

What I have shown is that $\eta=3+\sqrt{10}$ is a fundamental unit, so that $\mathscr{O}_K^*=\langle-1,\eta\rangle$. I think that first the finiteness of the norm has to be shown and that can be done with reasoning about them (both unit groups of the ring of integers of $K$ and $L$) both having a finite basis(??). Then maybe show that it divides a multiple of $3$ and then saying something about the norm of $\mathscr{O}_L^*$ over $L/\mathbb{Q}$. Should I try to compute $\mathscr{O}_L$ or is its unit group way easier to determine, like $\{\pm1\}$ or something? Literally clueless on how to attack this problem.

Comment: Looks like you and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3502927 are taking the same final exam. A fundamental unit of $L$ is of form $\eta^{1/n}$ (any root), for it to be in $L$, show that $n=1$ or $2$. The positivity of norm rules out $n=2$. Therefore $\eta$ is a fundamental unit. So $[\mathscr{O}_L^*:\mathscr{O}_K^*]$ comes from torsion, in which only when $p=3$, $L$ contains more than $2$  roots of unity.

Comment: @pisco That went way too fast for me. First of all, I don't understand why $\eta^{1/n}$ is the form of a fundamental unit in $L$. Secondly, why does that index come from a torsion and why is that only when $p=3$?